# Numbers Displaying in Wrong Direction With CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to list numbers within the same line using css. This is working EXCEPT the numbers are displaying in the wrong direction (i.e. 4 - 3 - 2 - 1, instead of 1 - 2 - 3 - 4). I tried using "direction: ltr" but that didn't help.

For my css I have this:

```
.pagination {
  clear: both;
  display: inline;
}

.page-number {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #555;
  padding: 10px;
  float: right;
}
```

And in my HTML view I have this:

```
<div class="pagination">
    <div class="page-number">1</div>
    <div class="page-number">2</div>
    <div class="page-number">3</div>
    <div class="page-number">4</div>
</div>
```

What do I need to change to make this display in the correct direction?

To clarify, I can't simply "float: left" because I want the numbers to appear on the right side of the page. So I want them as a totality to float right, but display in the correct order, from left to right.

Comment: Change the float to `left`

Comment: But I want the numbers to display on the right side of the page. So if I float: left that fixes the order issue, but also moves them to the wrong side of the page.

Comment: @Muirik just list the numbers in reverse-order and let `float: right;` correct it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done easily with `justify-content: flex-end;` in flexbox.

```css
.pagination {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.page-number {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #555;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pagination">
  <div class="page-number">1</div>
  <div class="page-number">2</div>
  <div class="page-number">3</div>
  <div class="page-number">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd like to add a pretty nice reference to flexbox layouts: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/. The main adventage of using flexbox is that u dont have to care about clearing the floats.

Comment: Yes, I like this option the best. It's the cleanest, and causes no conflicts or unwanted side effects.

Answer (score 2):

The problem arises because you are floating four elements to the right, but want them to display in the same order. Essentially, the first element gets floated to the right, then the second, then the third, etc.

In order to fix this, you need to use `float: left` on each of the elements, and give the pagination wrapper **itself** a `float: right`. Note that `display: inline` will be ignored if you use `float: right`, as a floated element automatically has `display: block` applied to it. As such, I've removed it from my example:

```css
.pagination {
  clear: both;
  float: right;
}

.page-number {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #555;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="pagination">
  <div class="page-number">1</div>
  <div class="page-number">2</div>
  <div class="page-number">3</div>
  <div class="page-number">4</div>
</div>
```

I've also created a working fiddle demonstrating this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/L2y4pn94/1/).

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks, this works. I initially steered away from this because when I added "float: right" with "display: inline" in the same class, my IDE gave me a warning saying the float would be ignored. But I guess that wasn't true. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, and sounds like a strange IDE ;) You could always get around the warning by adding a secondary container if you really wanted though :)

Comment: @Muirik It's actually the opposite - display: inline will be ignored once you set it to float: left or right.

Comment: yeah, float makes display=block regardless of what you specify, see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float

Comment: @Pangloss This is what my IDE tells me (by the way, this is a LESS file): "Property is ignored due to the display. With 'display: inline', the width, height, margin-top, margin-bottom, and float properties have no effect."

Answer (score 2):

make your divs display '**inline-block**' and text-align them in the main div '**right**'

```css
.pagination {
  clear: both;
  text-align:right;
}

.page-number {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #555;
  padding: 10px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="pagination">
    <div class="page-number">1</div>
    <div class="page-number">2</div>
    <div class="page-number">3</div>
    <div class="page-number">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a good option. The only issue is it adds padding between each element.

Comment: It's adding 2px of margin, i think he will survive with that xD

Answer (score 0):

Change the `float` to `left`.  Since you have the float set to `right`, its displaying them in the wrong order.

Look here:
https://jsfiddle.net/8f680j83/

Comment: But I want the numbers to display on the right side of the page. So if I float: left that fixes the order issue, but also moves them to the wrong side of the page.

Comment: You have to set the float:right on the parent element so the entire group of buttons goes to the right.